# Find median of interval data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am exploring different python libraries and I wondering how to find approximate median value of the grouped data set. Here is a table for a reference.

| Age | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 1-10 | 123 |
| 10-20 | 350 |
| 20-30 | 200 |
| 30-40 | 1700 |
| 40-50 | 360 |
| 50-60 | 60 |

Is there any function or do I need to hard code the formula and then have a loop going over each row and column of the dataset ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the median method? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.median.html

Comment: What is the expected output for your sample?

Comment: Thanks Nick, I have looked into that formula but I would like to make sure that as dataset depends on intervals, this dataframe.median function is supposed to calculate the median using the formula listed in blog ? (link: https://www.aplustopper.com/calculate-median-grouped-frequency-distribution/)

Comment: Hey Corralien, I haven't calculated the value so I am not sure what is desire output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to approximate median for discrete grouped data, you can approximate the median of the entire data set by interpolation using the formula:

median = L + interval * (N / 2 - CF) / F

L = lower limit of the median interval

N = total number of data points

CF = number of data points below the median interval

F = number of data points in the median interval

```py
# Approximating median by pure python and pandas functions
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'low_range':[1,11,21,31,41,51], 'high_range':[10,20,30,40,50,60], 'frequency':[123,350,200,1700,360,60]})

N = df['frequency'].sum()
# calulating L1
index = abs(df['frequency'].cumsum() - N/2).idxmin()
L1 = df['low_range'][index + 1]
cumsum_before = df['frequency'].cumsum()[index]
freq_medain = df['frequency'][index + 1]
width = df['high_range'][index + 1] - df['low_range'][index + 1]  + 1

median = L1 + (N/2 - cumsum_before ) / freq_medain * width

print("L1 = {} , cumsum_before = {}, freq_medain = {}, width = {}".format(L1, cumsum_before, freq_medain, width ) )
print("Approximated median = ", median)
```

> L1 = 31 , cumsum_before = 673, freq_medain = 1700, width = 10
> Approximated median =  35.25588235294118

If you have continuous data, you can use median_grouped function in statistics package.

```
# Approximating median by statistics grouped_median for continuous values and fixed intervals

import statistics as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'low_range':[1,10,21,31,41,51], 'high_range':[10,21,31,41,51,60], 'frequency':[123,350,200,1700,360,60]})

X = ((df['low_range'] + df['high_range'])/2).tolist()

f = df['frequency'].tolist()

# repeating values based on their frequencies
Y = [item for i,item in enumerate(X)
              for count in range(f[i])]

width = df['high_range'][0] - df['low_range'][0] + 1 

median = st.median_grouped(Y, width)
print("Approximated median = ", median)
```

> Approximated median =  35.25588235294118

Comment: Thank you, it helped